# EXCEL VBA Check if entry is empty or not 'space'

Tags: excel, vba, space

**Note.** Check if the `TextBox1` is empty is easy by using `TextBox1.Value = ""`.

But the problem is when the user hit the `spacebar`, `TextBox1` will still recognize it as a value. In such case, my data will appear as an empty cell with 1 `space` inside. So my **question** is, is there any method to check `TextBox1.value` for empty and also not consist of `space` whether there are 1 or more `space`? Million thanks to all.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

A common trick is to check like this:

```
trim(TextBox1.Value & vbnullstring) = vbnullstring
```

this will work for spaces, empty strings, and genuine null values

Comment: Dear Sir, this works perfectly! But is there any shorter version of it? Do I have to type or copy/paste for every TextBox?

Comment: You could use "" instead of vbNullString. (vbNullString is just an internal pointer to a common instance of ""). But I wouldn't worry about the length of the expression - it is stored in tokens, so the length doesn't matter. To save typing you can copy/paste the expression using Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V and change it as needed.

Comment: It is working well. I will be using `Trim(TextBox1.Value & "") = ""` from now onwards. Once again thank you :)

Comment: Using vbNullString is actually a better option since it requires less byte size to execute.

Answer (score 32):

Most terse version I can think of

```
Len(Trim(TextBox1.Value)) = 0
```

If you need to do this multiple times, wrap it in a function

```
Public Function HasContent(text_box as Object) as Boolean
    HasContent = (Len(Trim(text_box.Value)) > 0)
End Function
```

Usage

```
If HasContent(TextBox1) Then
    ' ...
```

Comment: Dear Sir, this is brilliant too. I would definitely use this in my project. I'm checking for a lot TextBox and this would be time saving. Thank you very much!

Comment: It gave me an error `Type mismatch`. Any idea how would that happen?

Comment: Probably because of the TextBox class.  I changed it to object here, so that should correct it!

Comment: Changed the comparison from `=` to `>` to better reflect the meaning of `HasContents`

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code to check whether value is present or not.

```
If Trim(textbox1.text) <> "" Then
     'Your code goes here
Else
     'Nothing
End If
```

I think this will help.

Comment: Your code is not working Sir. It's not checking for spacebar. By the way, I've marked above answer and I truly appreciate your faster reply too. Once again thank you!

Comment: This code will remove starting and ending space from value in textbox. The code must work, may I know what is the error you are getting please.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I meant is that I want to check whether the user hit the `spacebar` in the TextBox1. Your code do not check for single and multiple `space`. What I want is to only check for `space` without any other alphanumeric.

Comment: Then also this code will work. for example if I have entered just a space in textbox and nothing else then this code will consider that textbox contains null.
If you want to consider space then you can yes keyascii function.

Comment: I've revised your code, I think there should be `=` instead of `<>` in `Trim(textbox1.text) <> ""`.

Comment: In this case if there is no space in textbox then also code will return true.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following code to check if a textbox object is null/empty

```
'Checks if the box is null

If Me.TextBox & "" <> "" Then

        'Enter Code here...

End if
```