# Condition for Empty String in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

how do I check if the string variable is empty in vba?

if:

```
Dim StrFile1 As String, StrFile2 As String
Dim Text3 As String
Dim Len1 as Integer, Len2 As Integer 

  With NewMail
   Text3 = Cells(i, 3).Value
   StrPath = Cells(i, 2).Value & Text3
   Text = Cells(i, 1).Value

  .Subject = 
  ' adds the data in column3 with space as subject
  .From = 
  .To = Text
  .BCC = ""
  .TextBody = 

StrFile1 = Dir(StrPath & "*.txt")
   Len1 = Len(StrFile1)
   Do While Len(StrFile1) > 0
   .AddAttachment StrPath & StrFile1
   StrFile1 = Dir
   Loop

   StrFile2 = Dir(StrPath & "*.pdf")
   Len2 = Len(StrFile2)
   Do While Len(StrFile2) > 0
   .AddAttachment StrPath & StrFile2
   StrFile2 = Dir
   Loop

   If (Len1 & Len2) = 0 Then
   GoTo Last



  '.AddAttachment Text3
  .Send
End With
i = i + 1
Loop

Last:
End With
i = i + 1
Loop
```

**Now i want to check simultaneously if Len1 and Len2 are 0, if so then I want to go to Last.**

When I use this code I get a message/Compile error "**Want to end with without with"**
and
i am not sure if

```
If (Len1 & Len2) = 0 Then
       GoTo Last
```

this is a proper code.
and **Do i need to declare the label Last??**

Comment: Note: `IsEmpty()` is a VBA function, but won't work for empty strings I don't think. (Try it, `Debug.Print IsEmpty(StrFile1)` returns `FALSE`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EXCEL VBA Check if entry is empty or not 'space'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108948/excel-vba-check-if-entry-is-empty-or-not-space)

Comment: Wait, I think this may be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  **Why** are you checking for an empty string? Are you trying to see if there's a PDF or TXT file? Is that what the string check is for?

Comment: Yes...if the folder does not have either the .txt or .pdf files I want to end the current loop and go on to the next loop.(in this case a folder)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have many way to do that like below :

```
Dim StrFiles As String
StrFiles = Trim(StrFile1 & StrFile2)

If IsEmpty(StrFiles) Then
If StrFiles = vbNullString Then
If StrFiles = "" Then
If StrFiles = Empty Then
If Len(StrFiles) = 0 Then
```

you can use `+ operator` to check 2 strings are empty reference to your code, because `Len Function` returns an integer containing either the number of characters in a string

```
If (Len1 + Len2) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Is there a way to check whether 2 strings are empty simultaneously?

Comment: @Shank you can use : `If (Len1 + Len2) = 0 Then`

Comment: Any Idea why I am getting the error message " End with Without a with"?

Comment: @Shank Why you have `With NewMail` and 2 `End With` ?

Comment: I am sending email with attachment....so I am checking if the folder has either the txt or pdf file. If the doesnt have both then I want to end the loop.

No reason for 2 end.... I do not know how label works....I am thinking if it goes to label then it will execute the entire code else if it doesnt the the above code

Comment: is you have set `End If` for `If (Len1 & Len2) = 0 Then` ?

Comment: If (Len1 + Len2) = 0 Then

   GoTo Last

   End If

------------------- I get the same error message.

---------------do i end the if after the label??

Comment: is you have another `with` out of `With NewMail` because for each `with` you must use one `End With`, because in your code i see one `with` and 2 `End with`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Trim(strFile1 & vbNullString) = vbNullString` to check if the string is empty.

So:

```
If Trim(strFile1 & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
   Debug.print "Empty String!"
End If
```

Thanks to [@LordPeter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108957/4650297)

Comment: Oops, missed your answer. Removing mine which also suggested using `Trim`. +1 for using `vbNullString` over `""` (`vbNullString` is a null string pointer, `""` is uselessly allocated 2 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

`is.empty` doesn't exist for VBA, but the second option works.

Alternatively, you can write:

`(strFile1 & strFile2) = vbNullString`

or

`(strFile1 & strFile2) = ""`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is:

```
If Len(strFile1 & strFile2) > 0 Then
```

I did test to ensure that strings which aren't set return a length of 0, which appeared to be the case.

Comment: How do I check if (Len1 & Len2 ) = 0?