# VBA code checks if TextBox is empty, if so does not allow user to continue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with multiple text boxes. I would like a message box to appear if there is something in either TextBox2 and/or TextBox3, but nothing in TextBox1. I would also like it if the user was not able to continue if this occurs.

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub SubmitCommandButtom_Click()
If Len(TextBox1) = "" And Len(TextBox2) > 0 Or Len(TextBox3) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Unit Number must be entered to continue!"
End If
Sheets("Uneven Split Job Aid").Range("A2") = TextBox1.Value
Sheets("Uneven Split Job Aid").Range("B2") = TextBox2.Value
Sheets("Uneven Split Job Aid").Range("C2") = TextBox3.Value
```

This code currently only generates the message box when there is a value in Textbox3 and not in TextBox1, it doesn't matter if anything is in TextBox2. I would like it to check TextBox2 for a value as well. Also, when I click Ok on the message box, the Sub continues to run and inserts the values of the TextBoxes onto the worksheet. I would like if that did not happen if a message box appears.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `And`/`Or` Boolean logic, sometimes parentheses are required to ensure it is evaluated correctly. When it was:

```
If Con1 And Con2 Or Con3 Then
```

It was being being interpreted:

- Are both `Con1` And `Con2` True?

Or

- Is `Con3` True?

So, I added parentheses to read:

```
If Con1 And (Con2 Or Con3) Then
```

Which will be interpreted as:

- Is `Con1` True?

And

- Is either `Con2` or `Con3` True?

Which, if I understood your question correctly, is the logic you're aiming for. However, this does mean that if both `TextBox2` and `Textbox3` are empty, then it won't matter if `TextBox1` has anything; the `MsgBox` **won't** happen, and the rest of the code will.

---

**Further Boolean Analysis:**

Since `Con1` -- `Len(TextBox1) = ""` -- was always resolving to `False` *(see Note 1 below)*, the `And` check -- `Con1 And Con2` was always `false`. Thus, the only way that the `if` statement could resolve to `true` was if `Con3` resolved to `True`.

Since `Con3` was `Len(TextBox3) > 0`, the entire if statement was dependent on the length of the text in `TextBox3`!

---

**Notes:**

1. `Len(TextBox1) = ""` will always equal false. `Len()` returns a number not a string. I think you acidentally combined two methods for checking for an empty string. Either `TextBox1.Value = ""` or `Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0` would work; however, the combination doesn't make sense. *Although it took me most of typing up my answer before I caught this.*
2. It's better practice to use either `TextBox.Value` or `TextBox.Text` instead of just `TextBox` when accessing the contents.
3. The current check you have for the contents of `TextBox1`  will cause the `MsgBox` only when `TextBox1` is empty. This **excludes** white space characters, such as a space. If you also want the `MsgBox` when there are only white space characters, you should try something like: `Len(Trim(TextBox1.Value)) = 0` instead of what you had previously (`Len(TextBox1) = ""`).

   You can look at other suggestions for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14109060/9259306) You might also want to consider adding a similar check onto `TextBox2` and `TextBox3` if you don't want to trigger the `MsgBox` if they have white space characters, but not any non-white-space characters.

---

```
Private Sub SubmitCommandButtom_Click()

'Changed Len(TextBox1) = "" to Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 as per explanation above.
'Added .Value to length checks
If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 And (Len(TextBox2.Value) > 0 Or Len(TextBox3.Value) > 0) Then
    MsgBox "Unit Number must be entered to continue!"
Else
    Sheets("Uneven Split Job Aid").Range("A2") = TextBox1.Value
    Sheets("Uneven Split Job Aid").Range("B2") = TextBox2.Value
    Sheets("Uneven Split Job Aid").Range("C2") = TextBox3.Value
    'And any other code ....
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mistella! This worked great and from your  explanation I was able to apply this same logic to Textboxes 2 and 3 like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
If Len(TextBox1) = "" And Len(TextBox2) > 0 Or Len(TextBox3) > 0 Then
```

with:

```
If Len(TextBox1) = "" And Len(TextBox2 & TextBox3)  > 0 Then
```