# Else if statement not working as intended

Tags: excel, vba

In my userfield I have 2 textboxes for dates; if one of them is empty I want an error message to notify the user that they have to enter dates in both textboxes before continuing. I tried:

```
If IsEmpty(UserForm1.TextBox2.Value) And Not IsEmpty(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value) Or IsEmpty(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value) And Not IsEmpty(UserForm1.TextBox2.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please fill both date fields", vbInformation, "Date Range Error"
    End If
```

before my next steps in the macro but nothing happens.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If IsEmpty(UserForm1.TextBox2.Value) And Not IsEmpty(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value) Or IsEmpty(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value) And Not IsEmpty(UserForm1.TextBox2.Value) Then
MsgBox "Please fill both date fields", vbInformation, "Date Range Error"
End If


If UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = "(Blank)" Then
Sheets("FormResults").Range("C5").ClearContents 'Clear Product Type
Else
Sheets("FormResults").Range("C5").Value = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value 'Replace Product Type
End If
Sheets("FormResults").Range("C4").Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value 'Replace Store
Sheets("FormResults").Range("C3").Value = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value 'Replace Start Date
Sheets("FormResults").Range("D3").Value = UserForm1.TextBox3.Value 'Replace End Date

Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
If Len(UserForm1.TextBox2.Value) = 0 Or Len(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please fill both date fields", vbInformation, "Date Range Error"
End If
```

As pointed out in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108948/excel-vba-check-if-entry-is-empty-or-not-space), you can also compare to `vbNullString`.

Comment: Tried this before as well, doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Ah wait, `IsEmpty` is not appropriate here. Let me revise.

Comment: Seems to work, can I ask why IsEmpty doesnt work in this situation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108948/excel-vba-check-if-entry-is-empty-or-not-space. Maybe the [IsEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function) docs as well.

Comment: To further his ask, I would also add `Exit Sub` after his msgbox so the macro doesn't continue.