# Why is this VBA if statement not working?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this simple little piece of vba code that I would expect to return "Got to condition two" but instead it falls all the way to "three". Why?

```
Dim testValue as String
testValue = Null

If testValue = 8888 Then
    Debug.Print "Got to condition one"
ElseIf testValue = Null Then
    Debug.Print "Got to condition two"
Else
    Debug.Print "Got to condition three"
End If
```

Comment: I get an error on the second line, invalid use of `Null` (you can't assign this to a string.

Comment: Use `IsNull` to check for Null

Comment: possible duplicate of [Textbox null problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662751/textbox-null-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1. First, `Null`, in VBA, represents database nulls, and as a result, isn't equal to anything—even itself.  To check whether something is `Null`, you have to use the `IsNull` function.
2. But since `Null` is for databases, it's probably not what you wanted.  You probably instead want to set `testValue` to `Nothing`, which is the VBA "no value assigned" value.  `Nothing` is also not a simple type, so even if you're trying to check for whether something is `Nothing`, you can't use `=`; instead, you should write `ElseIf testValue Is Nothing`

Comment: 1) what is the `None` here: `Set testValue = None`? It doesn't compiles. 2) you can't use `Set testValue` and `testValue Is Nothing` with `Dim testValue As String`

Comment: @simoco I just axed the code snippet; I write Python at my day job and basically wrote a lovely hybrid of VBA and Python.  Sorry about that.

Comment: no problem, but your second item still not work: you can't test `testValue Is Nothing` if `testValue` has `String` type..

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can't put `Null` in a string variable, you should be getting an error on the `testValue = Null` assignment.

```
Sub Test()
Dim testValue As Variant
testValue = Null

If testValue = 8888 Then
    Debug.Print "Got to condition one"
ElseIf IsNull(testValue) Then
    Debug.Print "Got to condition two"
Else
    Debug.Print "Got to condition three"
End If
End Sub
```