# Dealing with Empty Cells in VBA for Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following code which is supposed to step through an array of fields and create two new arrays to add to a new recordset:

```
For Each Field In SDSRecordsets(i)
    Debug.Print (j)
    Debug.Print (Field.Value)
    fieldNames(j) = Field.Name
    If Field.Value = Null Then
        values(j) = ""
    Else
        values(j) = Field.Value
    End If
    j = j + 1
Next
```

The first time this loop runs, the Debug.Print lines print out 0 and then the string value in the first cell as it should. It then runs through the rest of it with no problems. The second time, it tries to add an empty cell. The first Debug.Print prints out 1, as it should, and the second prints out Null, also doing as it should. However, I then get a compile error on the line:

```
values(j) = Field.Value
```

Can anyone explain why it is reaching this line, because the way I see it, the If statement must be evaluating Null = Null as false for this to happen.

I've also tried doing this with:

```
If Not IsEmpty(Field.Value) Then
```

But that doesn't work either.

Comment: Right after posting this I realized that it should be: If Not IsEmpty(Field) Then and that works properly. I'd still like to know why the other way doesn't work though.

Comment: The condition, `Field.Value = Null`, can **never** be True because [Null is never equal to anything, not even Null.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5663965/77335)

Comment: Is there a function or something for testing Null values then? I'm used to languages like Java and C where null does equal null.

Comment: Did you look at the answer I linked? --> `IsNull()`

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't know why I didn't check that.

Comment: `values(j) = Nz(Field.Value)` will do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Nz` function:

```
For Each Field In SDSRecordsets(i)
    Debug.Print (j)
    Debug.Print (Field.Value)
    fieldNames(j) = Field.Name
    values(j) = nz(Field.Value,"")
    j = j + 1
Next
```

Also you can use `isnull([expr])` function, the direct comparison with `null` will not work